# python-docx: Parse a table to Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ms-word, python-docx

I'm using the `python-docx` library to extract ms word document. I'm able to get all the tables from the word document by using the same library. However, I'd like to parse the table into a panda data frame, is there any built-in functionality I can use to parse the table into data frame or I'll have to do it manually?
Also, is there a possibility to know the heading name in which the table lies inside? Thank you

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
document = Document('test.docx')

tabs = document.tables
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can extract tables from the document in data-frame by using this code :

```
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd
document = Document('test.docx')

tables = []
for table in document.tables:
    df = [['' for i in range(len(table.columns))] for j in range(len(table.rows))]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            if cell.text:
                df[i][j] = cell.text
    tables.append(pd.DataFrame(df))
print(tables)
```

You can get all the tables from the tables variable.

Comment: this is by far the best answer I have seen, this beautiful piece of code does what not even camlot or tabular could do. Awesome work!!!

Answer (score 1):

A similar alternative (but I did not test using multiple tables).
This gave me the dataframe format I was looking for:

```
for table in firstdoc.tables:
    doctbls=[]
    tbllist=[]
    rowlist=[]
    for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            rowlist.append(cell.text)
        tbllist.append(rowlist)
        rowlist=[]
    doctbls=doctbls+tbllist

finaltables=pd.DataFrame(doctbls)     
display(finaltables)
```

Comment: @abdulsaboor can you please help on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098471/extract-a-word-table-from-multiple-docx-files-using-python-docx