# How to add a Data Frame with indexes using python-docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-docx

I do realize this has already been addressed here (e.g., [Writing a Python Pandas DataFrame to Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596518/writing-a-python-pandas-dataframe-to-word-document), [python-docx: Parse a table to Panda Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254609/python-docx-parse-a-table-to-panda-dataframe)). Nevertheless, I hope this question was different.

I have used `value_counts()` and generated a DataFrame as below:

```
df = sns.load_dataset('tips')

object_cols = list(df.select_dtypes(exclude=['int', 'float', 'int64', 'float64', 'int32', 'float32']).columns)

# Value Count & Percentage for object columns
c = df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).T.stack().astype(int)
p = (df[object_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True)).T.stack() * 100).round(2)
cp = pd.concat([c,p], axis=1, keys=['Count', 'Percentage %'])

cp
```

The DataFrame looks like:

```
                 Count  Percentage %
sex      Female     87  35.66
         Male      157  64.34
smoker   No        151  61.89
         Yes       93   38.11
day      Fri       19   7.79
         Sat       87   35.66
         Sun       76   31.15
         Thur      62   25.41
time     Dinner   176   72.13
         Lunch     68   27.87
```

I'm trying to add the above DataFrame as a table in a document using `python-docx`

```
import docx 
from docx import Document

doc = Document()
doc.add_paragraph("Value Counts: ")

t = doc.add_table(cp.shape[0]+1, cp.shape[1])

# Set table style
t.style = 'Colorful List Accent 1'

# add the header rows.
for j in range(cp.shape[-1]):
    t.cell(0,j).text = cp.columns[j]

# add the rest of the data frame
for i in range(cp.shape[0]):
    for j in range(cp.shape[-1]):
        t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(cp.values[i,j])
        
filename = "output/ValueCOunts_Report.docx"
# save the docx
doc.save(filename)
```

I'm able to add the table as

```
Count   Percentage %
87      35.66
157     64.34
151     61.89
.....
.....
.....
```

[image]

How can I add the complete DataFrame with indexes as a table to document?

Comment: Simplest would be resetting the index `cp = cp.rename_axis(['Attr','Val']).reset_index()`

Comment: @anky. Thanks, it helps. But it fills the blanks in column `Attr`. Can it be possible to add the table with blanks?

Comment: yes , after the above step do: `cp['Attr'] = np.where(cp['Attr'].duplicated(),'',cp['Attr'])` and then execute your code

Comment: @anky Great! Thanks a lot. Please post it as an answer. I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little hacky solution as it brings the indexes to columns and manipulates the columns to look like index:

Reset the index and make use of [`series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `np.where` to fill the repeating values of the column with blank

```
cp = cp.rename_axis(['Attr','Val']).reset_index()
cp['Attr'] = np.where(cp['Attr'].duplicated(),'',cp['Attr'])
```

Then executing your code gives the following output:

[image]